# data type changes after reading the data to R

Tags: r, import, raster

I am working with MODIS data (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1elQjbQSMzG3xH9oQBzBvWGb8OKZTjMiI) and use R to extract the NDVI layer as tiff file.

```
library(gdalUtils); library(rgdal); library(raster)
setwd("D:/workspace")

files <- dir(pattern = ".hdf")
filename <- substr(files, 1, 4)
filename <- paste0("MODIS", filename, "ndvi.tif")

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i])
  gdal_translate(sds[1], ot = "Int16", of="GTiff", dst_dataset = filename[i])
}
```

In accordance to ArcGIS the output file has the data type int16. 
The range of the data values is 9991 to -1988. That is in line with the MODIS documentation (see page 9, table 1, https://vip.arizona.edu/documents/MODIS/MODIS_VI_UsersGuide_June_2015_C6.pdf). However, when I read the data back in R the data type changed.

```
x <- raster("D:/workspace/MODIS2000ndvi.tif")
x
dataType(x) # the data type changed to INT2S -32,767, 32,767
```

How do I get the original values to scale the NDVI index to -1 and 1? Any hint is appreciated!

UPDATE
The output of x looks as follows

```
> show(x)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4800, 4800, 23040000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 231.6564, 231.6564  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1111951, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : D:\workspace\MODIS2000ndvi.tif 
names       : MODIS2000ndvi 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

Comment: `32767` is the no data value, you should also follow @RobertH suggestion to re-scale NDVI to its original values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INT2S` is the same as `Int16` (2 byte signed integer), but I do not see how any of that is directly related to your question about NDVI. Can you show `x` (`show(x)`)

It looks like the values were multiplied with 10000 (in the original file, presumably to reduce file size). In that case, you can scale to [-1,1] with

```
x <- x / 10000
```

Comment: I added the output above. thanks for your advise, it does the job.